# C - Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have some structs declared, see here:

```
struct cache_1_way{
    int size;
    int set[1][1];
};

struct cache_2_way{
    int size;
    int set[2][2];
};
struct cache_4_way{
    int size;
    int set[2][4];
};
```

I create an array of a struct based on associativity, and then initialize the values in the array of structs.

```
struct cache_4_way cache[set_count];
for(int i = 0; i < set_count; i++){
    cache[i].size = 4;
    cache[i].set = {{0,0,0,0},
                    {0,1,2,3}};
}
```

In order to insert an element into my cache, I use a pre calculated set location value to index a certain struct object. However, I get the error, as mentioned in the title, whenever I try doing something like this:

```
for(int j = 0; j < cache[set_loc].size; j++){
    //code here
}
```

This doesn't make any sense. I'm able to initialize the cache array just fine, but when I try indexing the struct object at set_loc and accessing the size attribute, I get this error. I'm completely stumped on why I'm getting the error "Member reference base type 'int' is not a structure or union" every time I try indexing my cache array. Can someone please assist me here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C are not assignable. So this assigment attempt

```
cache[i].set = {{0,0,0,0},
                {0,1,2,3}};
```

has no chance of working, reagrdless of what syntax you use. A more "educated" attempt might look as follows

```
cache[i].set = (const int [2][4]) { {0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3} };
```

(which uses a *compound literal*), but it still won't work, since arrays in C are not assignable.

You can replace assigment with `memcpy` from a compound literal

```
memcpy(cache[i].set, (const int [2][4]) { {0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3} }, sizeof cache[i].set);
```

or assign values manually, element-by-element.

An even better idea might be to assign the whole struct, since structs are assignable (even when they have arrays inside)

```
for(int i = 0; i < set_count; i++){
  cache[i] = (const struct cache_4_way) { 4, { {0,0,0,0}, {0,1,2,3} } };
```

Comment: But that doesn't explain why I get errors on the declaration of my for loop 

for(int j = 0; j < cache[set_loc].size; j++)

Comment: @ThunderBow98: It is not possible to figure out what is causing the error in your `for` line (if that's indeed the line that triggers that error). It looks like you are omitting some cricuial details. The compiler is telling you that `cache[set_loc]` is not a structure, but an `int`. Apparently, it is indeed an `int`. Apparently you redeclared your `cache` somehow and not showing us how.

Comment: I found it... I'm passing the cache array into my function as an int array... damn now I have some serious restructuring to do

Comment: +1 for the `memcpy`/compound literal.  I have never run into that, despite its addition to the standard 18 years ago...